# Is there a way to have git add --patch skip all single line changes?

Tags: git

My team checks in an exported JSON file from a tool that we use (Postman) so that we can share the configuration easily. In a recent change to that tool, all the IDs (which are just GUIDs) get changed every time we export. This means that our diff has hundreds of one line meaningless changes (GUIDs changing), and then the actual meaningful change/addition that we've made.

If we check this in as-is then rebasing is really tricky, because the IDs seem to be completely random and so we get loads of meaningless merge conflicts. It's also annoying to review since the change we want reviewing is buried under hundreds of other meaningless changes. But using `git add --patch` is basically impossible because you have to skip hundreds of patches and then select the one you want, which might be near the bottom of the file.

I'm wondering if there's any clever scripting trick I can use to make it automatically discard all the one-liners, and only ask me about patches that are longer than one line. The actual patches we want are almost always longer than one line, so this would almost always work and make it much easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a reasonable workaround, using the `/` search feature of the `git add --patch` UI. Search for something in the hunk that's intended to have changed, stage that, then use `d` to discard everything else. This is probably a better approach than my original idea, because it would work even with a one-liner actual change.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the list of files is clearly established : `*.json` files, present in some clearly identifiable directories, perhaps with a specific name structure ... (meaning: you can easily target these files from `.gitattributes`)

If such is the case : your use case is a good fit for a `filter` (with a `clean / smudge` pair of scripts) that would replace the ever moving lines with fixed values when adding these files to git.

---

Here is a link to the docs: [git attributes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion)

relevant graphical description :

> [image: Figure 144. The “smudge” filter is run on checkout.]
> Figure 144. The “smudge” filter is run on checkout.
> [image: Figure 145. The “clean” filter is run when files are staged.]
> Figure 145. The “clean” filter is run when files are staged.

The target "filter" scripts to run should be defined in git's configuration,
the files to pass through this filter should be defined in a `.gitattributes` file.

You would need to set the following configuration once on each machine :

- deploy a script, let's call it `normalize-postman-ids`, that would be used when `git add`ing demo files,
- possibly a second script, let's call it `insert-valid-postman-ids`, that would be used when `git checkout`ing a commit,
- add a section in the `.git/config` file, that would describe a so called filer :

  ```
   [filter "postman-ids"]
       clean = path/to/normalize-postman-ids

       # if the values stored in git can be used straight away:
       smudge = cat
       # if you need some action on checkout:
       smudge = path/to/insert-valid-postman-ids
  ```

You would need to update and commit the `.gitattributes` file of your repo :

- in the `.gitattributes` file, target the files which should be filtered :

  ```
  # .gitattributes :
  postman*.json filter=postman-ids
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! I've found a simpler workaround that works for my current use case, but this is a really cool git feature that I wasn't aware of and will definitely read up on.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is :

- write a script, that, from a file name, is able to generate the correct patch
- use `git apply --cached` to apply this patch on the staging area, without modifying the worktree version

If you wrap the two actions in a script, accessible from your `PATH`, called `git-something` (e.g: `git-addpostman`), you can then add your files by calling `git addpostman $file` from within your repo.